# How can I clear stripes wizard form data?

Tags: java, forms, stripes

I am currently building an application in java, using the Stripes framework.  One of the web forms uses the Stripes wizard annotation.  After submitting the form, and returning to the form for a second entry, the form is repopulated with the previous data.

How can I clear out the form data that the Stripes Wizard has saved?

Answer (score 0):

Are you forwarding to same form again? You could redirect it to same form this will most certain clear all form data.